# Split elrang long name into shortname and host

Tags: erlang

I have need of this several times and I haven't come with a good solution
neither have found one.

Split a full node name like the one returned by

```
node()
```

which is in the form

```
FullName = 'node_name@localhost'
```

and I want to split in the node name, hostname

```
{ 'node_name', 'localhost'} = split_node_name(FullName)
```

So far I have converted to list and split on the @, but 
It feels ugly and something should be in the standard lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string:tokens` works like `split()` in other languages.

```
A = atom_to_list(node()).
string:tokens(A, "@").
```

In your case, it will return `['node_name', 'localhost']`.

If you want it to a tuple, use `list_to_tuple()/1`

```
list_to_tuple(A).
```

Comment: Well this is more or less  how I have been doing it, but this thing is common and you have to carry it from project to project. I'm going to mark your solution as valid but in this one erlang is a bit dissapointing. It looks also the reverse operation isn't on the standard lib either.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with somtehing like this:

```
list_to_tuple([list_to_atom(A)||A<-string:tokens(atom_to_list(node()), "@")]).
```